# Can i install an older version of Linux kernel into a new version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a college project on Adding a system call to Linux kernel

so  is it necessary that the kernel source code that i am compiling and the one that is already installed have to be of same version ?

I mean can i install an older version of kernel into a new version

Comment: Nope, you can install any version linux-kernel but certain user-space applications may fail if the apps use latest features in latest kernel.

Comment: If you want to do your project with an historic version (or make chancy kernel changes), consider running it in a virtual machine, possibly one such as qemu which can give you some visibility to debug.